# thread isalive always false c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Hi frnds i am new to thread concept.
Why threadTask.IsAlive always false;
i have tried with threadstate but i got "Unstarted" always.

```
foreach (DataRow TaskRow in dtCurrentTask.Rows)
            {

                sTaskId = TaskRow["TaskId"].ToString();
                sTaskAssigned = TaskRow["TaskAssigned"].ToString();

                threadTask = new Thread(() => RunTask(sTaskId));
                threadTask.Name = "thread_" + sTaskId;



                Console.WriteLine(threadTask.Name + " is alive :" + threadTask.IsAlive);
                if (!threadTask.IsAlive || sTaskAssigned == "0")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting thread :" + threadTask.Name);
                    Thread.Sleep(7000);

                    threadTask.Start();
                    UpdateTaskStatus(true);

                }



            }
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to be alive? In what line? It is not alive until it is started.

Comment: becuase you have no started it?

Answer (score 2):

Thread.IsAlive Property returns **true** if the thread has been started and has not terminated normally or aborted; otherwise, **false**.

See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

At the point where you are checking the IsAlive property, thread is not yet started. So at that point you are going to get false always.

To learn about using threads see this [Threading Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) at msdn.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop for threadTask variable, each time you are creating a new instance. So whenever you check for isAlive, it will refer to the newly created instance in the current loop and not the previously created thread, therefore it always return false.

Comment: then how do create instance

Answer (score 0):

Checking if thread is alive after starting it, returns false. This is because the thread does not begin inmediatly. Instead, check its state is stopped:

```
if(t.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped)
```

Thread is stopped when finished task. You can check another codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).